# Django send errors to angular

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

For my backend in django I have it set to the email and username fields must be unique. If they aren't unique I want it to send back to angular saying which one isn't unique how would I go about doing this. Currently it just gives me 400 bad request.

This is my register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import {RegisterService} from './account.service'

import {Router} from '@angular/router'



@Component({ 
    templateUrl: 'register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['register.component.css']
 })
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;


    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private registerService: RegisterService,
        private router: Router,
        ) { }

    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({   
            username: ['', Validators.maxLength(15)],
            password: ['', Validators.maxLength(20)],
            email: ['', Validators.email],    
            first_name: ['' , Validators.maxLength(15)],
            last_name: ['', Validators.maxLength(15)]
        });
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.form.controls; }

    emailError : string = '';
    usernameError : string = '';

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            return; 
            
        }
        
        this.registerService.register(this.form.value).subscribe(
            response => {
                alert('User Created')
            },
            (error: any) => 
            {
                console.log(error)
            }
        );       
    }
```

This is my account.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {HttpClient} from  '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService{
   
    
    private apiRoot = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    register(userData): Observable<any>{
        console.log(userData)
        return this.http.post(this.apiRoot.concat('api/users/'),userData);
    }

}
```

And this is my serializer.py for Django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required = True,
        validators = [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required = True,
        min_length = 8
        )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required = True,
        validators = [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
        )
        
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        required = True
        )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        required = True
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

Comment: Thats what the console.log(error) is doing just showing me what angular was getting form django. But when I do a bad input on the backed I can see it say                                                                     
 HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "username": [
        "This field must be unique."
    ],
    "email": [
        "This field must be unique."
    ]
}

Comment: can you check by clearing your User model in Django admin and try again, seems like you are trying to create accounts with the same username and email over and over again.